# check the existence of the folder and delete the temp files

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I use batch file commands to delete the temp files in the system. The command works OK.

This code, works normally, but there is a flaw:

```
FOR /D %%p IN ("C:\Temp\*.*") DO rmdir "%%p" /s /q

cd c:\temp
del /F /s /q *.* >c:\DelTempLog.txt
rd /s /q %systemdrive%\$Recycle.bin >c:\DelTempLog.txt

FOR /D %%p IN ("C:\Windows\Installer\$PatchCache$\*.*") DO rmdir "%%p" /s /q 

cd C:\Windows\Installer\$PatchCache$
del /F /s /q *.* >c:\DelTempLog.txt

FOR /D %%p IN ("C:\Windows\Temp*.*") DO rmdir "%%p" /s /q

cd C:\Windows\Temp
del /F /s /q *.* >c:\DelTempLog.txt 
del /q /s %tmp% >c:\DelTempLog.txt
```

Today I faced an **exception** where `c:\temp` folder did not exist on the server.

It deleted half of the files under `c:\windows\system32`.

1. I want to add an `IF` command after changing the DIR before deleting anything.
2. Also, please advise me how to do **logging** activity in a better way.

Answer (score 1):

At an elementary level if you specify the full path on the command line then it cannot delete files from anywhere else.

```
del /F /s /q "c:\temp\*.*?"
```

There is also no need to change the directory before issuing the command.

The `?` suppresses a prompt that asks if you are sure that you want to delete all files.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "logFile=c:\deltemplog.txt"

    (for %%a in (
        "c:\temp" "c:\windows\temp" "%temp%" 
        "%systemdrive%\$Recycle.bin" "C:\Windows\Installer\$PatchCache$"
    ) do if not exist "%%~a\" (
        echo [ ERROR ]: "%%~a" does not exist
    ) else pushd "%%~a" && (
            echo [ pushd ]: changed to "%%~a"
            echo rmdir . /s /q 
            popd
        ) || (
            echo [ ERROR ]: Failed to change to "%%~a"
        )
    ) > "%logFile%"
```

For each folder in the list, change to it and if the command did not fail, remove the current folder (this will remove the content, not the folder, as it is the current one).

The rmdir commands are only echoed. If the output (in the log file) is correct, remove the `echo` command that prefixes `rmdir`

Answer (score 0):

How about, before your batch-as-it-stands, you try

```
md c:\temp 2>nul
if not exist c:\temp\. echo No c:\temp!&goto :eof
```

Answer (score 0):

My preference is to use the `%CD%` built-in value, then try to move to the folder and see if it worked, as in:

```
set CURDIR=%CD%
pushd C:\Temp
if '%CD%'=='%CURDIR%' (
    echo Failed to move to C:\Temp
) else ( 
   [code to do your deletions] 
)
popd
```

I prefer to push and pop a directory rather than a hard `CD` to it, simply because then you can always get back to where you were without having to know where that was.